# SQL filter query on joined column

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following SQL which selects all ManifestoBatches and gives me a count of each batches items (ManifestoItems):

```
SELECT m.Id, u.UserName, m.TotalRows, m.DateCreated, count(i.Id) as Items
 FROM ManifestoBatches as m
 left join ManifestoItems as i on m.Id = i.BatchId
 inner join AmzUsers as u on m.CreatedBy = u.Id
 GROUP BY m.Id
 ORDER BY Items DESC
 LIMIT 0, 10
```

This works fine; however, I would like to only count the ManifestoItems which have the property ManifesoItems.ScannerId not equal to null.

So, I tried adding this:

```
where NULLIF(i.ScannerId, '') is not null
```

But, this filters the entire result set and only gives me ManifestoBatches where ManifestoItems.ScannerId is not null.  **Instead, I want it to get all ManifestoBatches, but only give me a count of ManifestoItems where ManifestoItems.ScannerId is not null.**

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
count(i.Id)
```

use

```
SUM(CASE WHEN i.ScannerId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I changed it to `SUM(CASE WHEN NULLIF(i.ScannerId, '') IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Items` and it works perfectly.

Comment: My code is a standard SQL.  The two other answers offer very nice short-cut for MySQL that represents `true/false` as `1/0`.

Comment: I had tried the other two but they didn't seem to work for me.  Only this one worked.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is the `left join`.  This produces `NULL` when the values do not match.  But it sounds like you have `NULL` values in the field anyway.  This may solve your problem:

```
SELECT m.Id, u.UserName, m.TotalRows, m.DateCreated, count(i.Id) as Items
FROM ManifestoBatches m join
     ManifestoItems i
     on m.Id = i.BatchId inner join
     AmzUsers u
     on m.CreatedBy = u.Id
WHERE i.ScannerId is not null
GROUP BY m.Id
ORDER BY Items DESC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

If you still want the `left join`, then move the logic to the `count()`:

```
SELECT m.Id, u.UserName, m.TotalRows, m.DateCreated, sum(i.ScannerId is not null) as Items
FROM ManifestoBatches m left join
     ManifestoItems i
     on m.Id = i.BatchId inner join
     AmzUsers u
     on m.CreatedBy = u.Id
GROUP BY m.Id
ORDER BY Items DESC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

add

```
sum(i.ScannerId is not NULL)
```

to your selection.